# IOS saving images as circle in cameraRoll

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to save images as circular images to the album in iOS. I tried to mask image in circular shape and it is working fine in a image view but when I save the same image it is getting saved as the original image.

Here is my code:

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize imageview, photo;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


self.imageview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.imageview.layer.cornerRadius = imageview.bounds.size.width/2;
self.imageview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
self.imageview.layer.borderColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:13/255 green:70/255 blue:131/255 alpha:1.0].CGColor;}



-(IBAction)takephoto:(id)sender{
picker1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker1.delegate = self;

[picker1 setSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)];
[self presentViewController:picker1 animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

-(IBAction)chooseExisting:(id)sender{
picker2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker2.delegate = self;

[picker2 setSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary)];
[self presentViewController:picker2 animated:YES completion:NULL];}

 - (IBAction)save:(id)sender {



//NSString *shareText = @"download my add with the follow up link";for textwrking.

NSArray *itemsToShare =@[imageview.image];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC =[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes =@[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook /* this is like excuding activities like fb,twitterand all  whtever we login on ios, we can use this code  */];

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];}

  -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
photo=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[imageview setImage:photo];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];}
```

`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this solution without using imageview.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithRoundedCornersSize:(float)cornerRadius usingImage:(UIImage *)original
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, original.size.width, original.size.height);

    // Begin a new image that will be the new image with the rounded corners
    // (here with the size of an UIImageView)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(original.size, NO, 1.0);

    // Add a clip before drawing anything, in the shape of an rounded rect
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:frame
                                cornerRadius:cornerRadius] addClip];
    // Draw your image
    [original drawInRect:frame];

    // Get the image, here setting the UIImageView image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // Lets forget about that we were drawing
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
- (IBAction)share:(id)sender {

    //NSString *shareText = @"download my add with the follow up link";for textwrking.

    NSArray *itemsToShare =@[[self imageWithRoundedCornersSize:self.imageview.image.size.width*2 usingImage:self.imageview.image]];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC =[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes =@[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook /* this is like excuding activities like fb,twitterand all  whtever we login on ios, we can use this code  */];

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

FYI this image rounding function works very well with square images, not that good with rectangular images. For rectangular images you got to crop the part of the image in a circular fashion and draw a new image.

Comment: tried this one still its saving as normal image please someone help me

Comment: still its not working , i can send my file, can u give ur email id please  have a look its would be helpful.,,

Comment: satheesh4590@gmail.com

Comment: i just mailed my file please check it and let me know

Comment: check your mail I have replied

Comment: yess its working fine  now , trying to  add my other codes, thanks alot once again